# jquery to sum two inputs on dynamic table and display in third

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the SO community I have got a script that adds rows with unique names to a table. I want to take two inputs on each row and multiply them together and display result in a third input.

the fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/231/

My code is:
**HTML**

```
<table class="order-list">
  <tr><td>Product</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Total</td></tr>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="product" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qty" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="linetotal" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="grandtotal">
    Grand Total Here
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var counter = 1;
jQuery("table.order-list").on('change','input[name^="product"]',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="product' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="price' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="qty' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="total' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.order-list').append(newRow);
});

jQuery("table.order-list").on('click','.deleteRow',function(event){

    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});

$('table.order-list tr').each(function() {
   var price = parseInt( $('input[id^=price]', this).val(), 10 );
   var qty   = parseInt( $('input[id^=qty]'  , this).val(), 10 );
   $('input[id^=linetotal]', this).val(price * qty);
});
```

So currently I cant get the js to fire that gets the product of the two cells, qty and price. I want to display result in linetotal.

The last part of this would be to display the sum of all linetotals as a grand total in the div `grandtotal`

Help appreciated as always.

Comment: You're only giving the `<input>` elements a `name` attribute, but using the `id` selector (`[id^=price]`). It's much easier to give them a specific class than having to use that "id starts with" selector. Also, when do you want the line totals to be calculated? And when do you want the grand total to be calculated? On what event(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only giving the  elements a name attribute, but using the id selector ([id^=price]). It's much easier to give them a specific class than having to use that "id starts with" selector. Also, when do you want the line totals to be calculated? And when do you want the grand total to be calculated? On what event(s)?

Here's my interpretation of how it should look:

```
<table class="order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Product</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Total</td></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="product" /></td>
            <td>$<input type="text" name="price" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty" /></td>
            <td>$<input type="text" name="linetotal" readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Product" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                Grand Total: $<span id="grandtotal"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        counter++;

        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="product' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td>$<input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="qty' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td>$<input type="text" name="linetotal' + counter + '" readonly="readonly"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);

        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("change", 'input[name^="price"], input[name^="qty"]', function (event) {
        calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
        calculateGrandTotal();
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("click", "a.deleteRow", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        calculateGrandTotal();
    });
});

function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();
    var qty = +row.find('input[name^="qty"]').val();
    row.find('input[name^="linetotal"]').val((price * qty).toFixed(2));
}

function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="linetotal"]').each(function () {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QAa35/

In your JS, you weren't using `linetotal` for the one dynamic input's `name`. There were other several minor modifications I made. You might as well use `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` since you do have those sections in the `<table>`. Also, I don't think it's a good design to have a new row automatically added when the "product" inputs are changed. That can happen often, and their intent may not be to add a new product...a button is much more friendly. For example, say you type in "asdf" to the first "product" input, then click somewhere. A new row is added. Say you made a typo so you go back and change it to "asd", then click somewhere. Another new row is added. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Thanks Ian, works perfectly. Thanks for your assistance. I hear you on the button rather than the automatic entry. My design has an autocomplete on the product table but it still can create the multiple rows so button is a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Ian, a few questions about your syntax if you don't mind, just for my learnings. what is the a appended in `a.deleteRow` ? why do you have `+row` in the two functions and `+=` for the cols? which piece of code is actually setting/changing the linetotal value when price and qty change? `val((price * qty).toFixed(2))`? Thanks for your help and apologies if these are basic questions, just want to ensure your teachings are not in vain :-)

Comment: @Smudger No problem at all, glad I can help! Yeah, the whole idea with the button was just my preference but it should be easy to add back in the functionality you had. Just wanted to suggest it :) And I will follow up your questions with some comments in just a minute.

Comment: `a.deleteRow` is just to help speed up the jQuery selector process. Using `a` means select all `<a>` elements (it's a tagname selector) and then filter by ones that have the class `deleteRow`. Selecting by tagname first should help speed it up (although it may be unnoticeable). The combination of `a` and `.deleteRow` is only because you know the elements with the class `deleteRow` will definitely be `<a>`. If you had a variety of element tags, you'd have to drop the `a`. But you have a specific, known HTML structure so you can use that :)

Comment: I have `+row...` because the `+` is an operator for converting a string to number. It's really converting the result of `row.find('input[name^="price"]').val()` because the `.val()` method always returns a string. At the same time, later when I have `price * qty`, they should automatically be converted (if possible) anyways, because of the `*` operator. So technically, the `+`s are unnecessary, I just like to explicitly do things sometimes.

Comment: I used `+=` for the `cols` because it just made it more readable. Instead of having `var cols = "REALLY BIG STRING";` on one line, it made more sense, visually, to do that. But all it's doing is concatenating the strings into one big one...but doing so on multiple lines.

Comment: And yes, you're absolutely right that `.val((price * qty).toFixed(2))` is the part that actually sets the line totals. It multiplies the price by quantity (obviously), and converts it to a string with two decimal places (`.toFixed(2)`). Then it uses the `.val()` to set the textbox's value to the result. The fact that `row.find()` is used first is to target the specific row that was just changed, otherwise it would have to loop through the whole table every time. Luckily, you can tell what specific textbox changed (and therefore what specific row to update/recalculate).

Answer (score 1):

This function should do the trick:

```
function updateGrandTotal() {

    var prices = [];
    $('input[name^="price"]').each(function () {
        prices.push($(this).val());
    });

    var qnts = [];
    $('input[name^="qty"]').each(function () {
        qnts.push($(this).val());
    });

    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++){
        total += prices[i] * qnts[i];
    }

    $('#grandtotal').text(total.toFixed(2));

}
```

You just need to bind it to the table change event to update the grand total every time an input changes:

```
$("table.order-list").change(updateGrandTotal);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Gshb/1/) is a working fiddle.